# How to update a dataframe in a for loop with a calculation from certain values of the df?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I´m trying to update the values of `Results` dataframe in a `for` loop, saving in this the results of a forecast calculation: multiply the value of the column `ForeC` from the `forecast` dataframe by the numbers of days in the column `Days` in `df3`. I have 3 dataframes like this:

Results:

```
  Shops       Q1     Q2
0    Ra       0       0
1    Co       0       0
2    Si       0       0
3   Lem       0       0
4    Fa       0       0
```

Forecast:

```
  Shops  Quarter  ForeC  Type
0    Ra      Q1    199    A
1    Co      Q2    145    A
2    Si      Q2    119    A
3    Ra      Q2    133    B
4    Co      Q1    123    B
5    Si      Q2    111    A
6    Fa      Q1    121    A
```

Df3:

```
  Shop  Days   Type
0   Ra    25    A
1   Ra    29    B
2   Fa    33    A
3   Fa    53    B
4   Co    30    A
5   Co    30    B
6  Lem    29    A
7  Lem    20    B
8   Si    22    A
9   Si    25    B
```

This is my code (with the df definition):

```
import pandas as pd

results = pd.DataFrame([['Ra',0,0],['Co',0,0],['Si',0,0],['Lem',0,0],['Fa',0,0]], columns=['Shops','Stock Q1','Stock Q2'])
forecast = pd.DataFrame([['Ra',1,199,'A'],['Co',2,145,'A'],['Si',2,119,'A'],['Ra',2,133,'B'],['Co',1,123,'B'],['Si',2,111,'A'],['Fa',1,121,'A']], columns=['Shops','Quarter','ForeC','Type'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([['Ra',25,'A'],['Fa',33,'A'],['Co',30,'A'],['Lem',29,'A'],['Si',22,'A'],['Ra',25,'B'],['Fa',33,'B'],['Co',30,'B'],['Lem',29,'B'],['Si',22,'B']], columns=['Shop','Days','Type'])

for index, row1 in results.iterrows():
    for idx, row2 in forecast.iterrows():
        if row2['Quarter']=='Q1':
            results.at[index, 'Q1']=results.loc[index, 'Q1']+(df3.loc[((df3['Shop'] ==row2['Shops']) & (df3['Type'] == row2['Type'])),'Days'])*row2['ForeC']
```

When I run this there are no errors but the the dataframe results don´t change
A solution like this o another way of solution is welcome :)

Comment: You seem to have an answer, but ... is that really what you want? It looks to me like the values in the output don't match what you describe (I might be wrong, of course). And I'd advise against iterating (explicitly) over dataframe rows to manipulate the dataframe: that's usually not a reasonable approach, since it doesn't use Pandas' potential. So, could you add the expected output for your sample to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

Firsty, I must inform you that your code present some minor errors due to the DataFrame's structure which you aren't following. Precisely:

1. **row2 Quarters hold numeric values between 1-2**, and you are comparing them as if they were Strings, therefore, this validations will always return False and the inner sequence won't run.
2. You are trying to access column with key 'Stock Q1' using 'Q1' instead, this won't work as **the column you are trying to reference does not exists**.

Now, regarding your question and editing with regards to your comments to my previous response, if you are being provided a series, then you have would have to sum them all.

I propose you that you first collect all shops and types like this:

```py
# Separate shops and types
shops = forecast['Shops'].unique()
types = forecast['Type'].unique()
```

Now, we attend each shop and type correspondingly and update their values using the loc function, which requires 2 parameters: the criteria to find their corresponding row and the column to modify.

**I will separate the total of forecast as *"t_foreC"* and do the same with the days as *t_days* **

```py
# Iterate through all shops
for s in shops:
  for t in types:
    t_days = sum((df3.loc[(df3['Shop'] == s) & (df3['Type'] == t)])['Days'])
    t_foreC = sum((forecast.loc[(forecast['Shops'] == s) & (forecast['Type'] == t)])['ForeC'])
    results.loc[(results['Shops'] == s), 'Stock Q1']+= t_days * t_foreC
```

This should return you the following result:

|  | Shops | Stock Q1 | Stock Q2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Ra | 8300 | 0 |
| 1 | Si | 5060 | 0 |
| 2 | Co | 8040 | 0 |
| 3 | Lem | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | Fa | 3993 | 0 |

I'm storing everything under the column "Quarter Q1", but given its corresponding criteria, you could apply it either to Quarter Q1 or Q2 .

Comment: The code is just for the first quarter. The code isn´t working good yet, now is making a calculation but is adding the multiplication of all the stores in each store, when you only have to add it for the corresponding store

Comment: It should multiply the (days(of a certain type(A or B)))*foreC just when the Shop in dataframe "results" is the same that the Shop in dataframe "forecast"

Comment: I add an: "if row1['Shops']==row2['Shops']:"
With this and your corrections it work perfect. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, I have another issue, when you have a large amount of rows in forecast, it could appear that when you use this:
(int(df3.loc[((df3['Shop'] ==row2['Shops']) & (df3['Type'] == row2['Type'])),'Days'])*row2['ForeC'])
You have the problem that what is inside the int() is a series, in this case, what I can do?

Comment: @emiheruru I have provided you with a more complete answer, it should work well for it. These are the results I have obtained. 
 Shops Stock Q1 Stock Q2
0 Ra 8300 0
1 Si 5060 0
2 Co 8040 0
3 Lem 0 0
4 Fa 3993 0